# Importing data from JSP file (CSV format) into Excel with Spring framework

Tags: spring, excel, import, jsp-tags

ALL!

I have a question related to Spring, JSP. I generate a JSP file with data from database and I want to import it to Excel. I actually know how to do it using either Controllers or just providing Java code in JSP file itself. (Abstract(J)ExcelView). But my question is if I can do it without any explicit java code in JSP itself, only using custom tags. So everything will be done only with help of one .jsp and some xml configuration files. Tips on writing own taglib are welcomed.

Thank you! Would really appreciate your help!

Regards, Nigar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was that easy at the end. here is a taglib. placed it to WEB_INF/tags folder

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ attribute name="contentType" required="true" type="java.lang.String" %>
<%@ attribute name="file" required="true" type="java.lang.String" %>


<% response.setHeader("Content-disposition",file ); 
response.setHeader("Content-type",contentType);%>
```

and this is jsp file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="tg" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>    
<tg:excel contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel" file="attachment;filename=mf.xls" />
```

afterwards simple html table building with data ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like writing normal html:

```
<c:foreach var="row" items="${table}">
  <c:out value="${row[0]}">;<c:out value="${row[1]}">;<c:out value="${row[2]}">;
</c:foreach>
```

Then the only think you need to set correct is the http response header.

*Attention: this will not work with jspx - because jspx will remove the whitespaces (line breaks)*

Anyway: I do not recommend this way.

Comment: Either I dont understand here smth (sorry in this case, im not really good in spring), or I have explained smth wrong. I need to write this data from jsp (which I have already got printed to the jsp like u have written) to Excel. 
response.reset();

response.setHeader("Content-type","application/xls");

response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline;filename=nombre.csv"); 

how do I do the same without plain java code? I have an assignment to do the same ,but using only tags. totally stuck on it. Thank you for an answer!

Comment: @Nigul: sorry now the question is clean. I guess it is not possible to set the header from inside of an jsp without java, except when you write your own tag, and then use that tag. -- But (let me ask that question) why do you want to do this? Isn't it much easier to do this ALL (CSV content and header) the spring MVC controller?

Comment: I know it is. And I can do it this way, no problem ;) it is an assignment for my course. im not really asked how i want to do it, just have to implement it. I assumed I may need my own tag :S cause after searching in internet for a few days, got nothing.. so, time to start learning how to write tags :D thank you anyway!

Comment: @Nigul writing tags is not complicated